# VmHWM only 25% whereas it should be around 80%

Tags: memory, out-of-memory

I have a dedicated MySQL server equipped with 128 GB RAM. MySQL recently gets killed by the oom-killer, although MySQL is configured to use 95 GB in the worst case. In my research I came across this:

```
# cat /proc/11895/status
Name:   mysqld
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   11895
Pid:    11895
PPid:   24530
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    27      27      27      27
Gid:    27      27      27      27
Utrace: 0
FDSize: 1024
Groups: 27
VmPeak: 72188044 kB
VmSize: 72122508 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:  33294036 kB
VmRSS:  32829668 kB
VmData: 72076496 kB
VmStk:        88 kB
VmExe:     11800 kB
VmLib:      3608 kB
VmPTE:     73388 kB
VmSwap:  4139376 kB
Threads:        59
```

I'm wondering, why is the VmHWM and VmRSS at only around 33 GB whereas on another server (also a slave to the same master, configured almost the same (except for buffer pool), except, that it has 256 GB RAM), the output is as follows:

```
# cat /proc/51298/status
Name:   mysqld
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   51298
Pid:    51298
PPid:   50443
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    27      27      27      27
Gid:    27      27      27      27
Utrace: 0
FDSize: 2048
Groups: 27
VmPeak: 243701128 kB
VmSize: 239628932 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:  209331200 kB
VmRSS:  205515868 kB
VmData: 239582156 kB
VmStk:        88 kB
VmExe:     11800 kB
VmLib:      3608 kB
VmPTE:    409600 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:        281
```

Here the memory is used to about 80%, whereas on the oom-killed server it's only about 25% (note, that these values where observed shortly before the oom-killer strikes again). What could be the reason? There is no competing process. And what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out a colleague was experimenting with [large-page-support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/large-page-support.html) and didn't revert all changes he made. When I ran

```
sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=0
```

and commented out this section in the `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
# Hugepage Support MySQL
#vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 27
#kernel.shmmax = 10737418240
#kernel.shmall = 23689185
#vm.nr_hugepages = 46268
```

it freed up 90 GB which were wasted. This could be seen in the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`:

```
HugePages_Total:   46268
HugePages_Free:    46268
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Huge thanks go out to Matthew Ife. Please upvote [his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/850184/115795) over at serverfault.com instead of this one.

Comment: note: shmmax and shmall aren't related to hugepages.